# Computing a formula using do/while statements

Tags: c++

who knows how to calculate the sum using the do/while operator using the formula below?
I would be grateful for any help.

[image]

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Are you sure that the formular ist correct? What does `i-1` mean? Where does the sum start at? I think it should be `i=1`.

Comment: I have not tried anything. I do not know how to work with this sigma at all. According to the curriculum, we did not yet have higher mathematics, and in programming problems we already have sigma ...

Comment: It's F = (1/1 + 18*1) + (1/2 + 18 * 2) + (1/3 + 18 * 3) + ... + (1/15 + 18 * 15). It's a pretty simple loop.

Comment: A sigma is just a way to express essentially a loop. Does it have to be a do`do-while`, because `for` may be better to explain.

Comment: Yes you are right, Thomas. I have a typo.

Comment: Thank you Thomas.

Comment: Just care with integer division (`1 / 2 == 0`) whereas you need floating point (`1. / 2 == 0.5`).

Comment: Usually, sigmas are implemented as a `for` loop, especially when the range is fixed.  Why do you need a `do-while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula can be translated like this:

```
double i = 1;
double sum = 0;

do{
    sum += (1/i + 18*i);
    i--;
} while (i < 16);
```

I'm not really sure that using a `do while` is the best option, it would probably be better with a `for` loop like so:

```
double sum = 0;
for (double i = 1; i < 16; ++i){
    sum += (1/i + 18*i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer, John =)